# Printing binary char in c

Tags: c

I cannot, for the love of myself figure out what the logic is behind this C code.

Supposedly, the following should print out the binary representation of an unsigned char x, and we are only allowed to fill in the blanks.

```
void print_binary(unsigned char x) {
    int b = 128;

    while (__________________) {

        if (b <= x) {
            x -= b;
            printf("1");
        } else
            printf("0");

        ______________________;
    }
}
```

Of course I could game the program by simply ignoring the lines above. However I'm under the impression that this is not really the way to do things (it's more of a hack).

I mean really now, the first condition checks whether 128 is <= the char, but isn't an unsigned char, what, 255 bytes? So why is it only printing '1' in it.

Perhaps I'm missing something quite obvious (not really a c programmer) but the logic just doesn't sink into me this time.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? And if you can give me a clue without completely saying the answer, that would be heavenly.

Comment: The second blank is probably `b /= 2`; the first is presumably `b != 0`.

Comment: I invite you to look to the list on the right/left of Related questions. and pick [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format?rq=1). Further, "but isn't an unsigned char, what, 255 bytes" ?? I dunno about your platform, but on mine an unsigned char is *one* byte.

Comment: This question is more about maths than about C.

Comment: @Joni My exact feeling - which is weird since this is supposed to be an "Are you familiar enough with C?" test.

Answer (score 3):

```
void print_binary(unsigned char x) {
    int b = 128;

    while (b != 0) {

        if (b <= x) {
            x -= b;
            printf("1");
        } else
            printf("0");

        b = b >> 1;
    }
}
```

The binary representaion for b is `10000000`. By doing `b >> 1` and checking `b <= x` we can check each bit on `x` is `1` or `0`.

Comment: did you miss a "`b = `"?? "`b = b >> 1;`"

Comment: @raj raj. yes, Thanks. was a typo.

Comment: he asked for a hint: "And if you can give me a clue without completely saying the answer", but you gave him the answer

Answer (score 1):

You wanted only a clue: Value of the current bit is always bigger, than the combination of less significant bits after it. Thus code tries to test only the most significant '1'-bit on each iteration of loop.

Answer (score 0):

If we disregard the original code, the most intuitive way to do this would be:

```
void print_binary (uint8_t x) 
{
  for(uint8_t mask=0x80; mask!=0; mask>>=1)
  {
    if(x & mask)
    {
      printf("1");
    }
    else
    {
      printf("0");
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: There are advantages to not including the newline in the output from the function.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Without a specification of what the function should do, who can tell.

Comment: Do we really need an `if else`? What about this? `for(int i=7; i>=0; i--)
  printf("%d", (x>>i)&1);`

Comment: The original code was a form of specification; it does not include a newline at the end of the output, and for the sake of being generally useful, it should not include the newline.